# CSS :Not attribute

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a few HTML tables. These tables do not have CSS classes. The two tables have `width="100%"` attribute. Other tables don't have the `width` attribute.

Using only CSS I need to set the width of the tables which don't have `width=100%`. Something like this:

```
table:not(width="100%"){
    width: myValue;
}
```

Comment: Do you want ALL tables with a width of 100%?

Comment: No. Tables that have no Width attribute should have width=50%. I can't edit xml that's why I should do in with css only.

Comment: Note that `:not` css selector not working in IE8 and below.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Attribute selectors are surrounded by `[]`, so your selector should look like this instead:

```
table:not([width="100%"]) {
    width: myValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use a class on that table and put that in the not

```
table:not(.foo) {

}
```

you need a selector in the not and width = 100% is not one

Answer (score -1):

How about using inline styles for the tables you want to have different widths?

```
<table style="width:95%">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

OR a separate class:

```
<table class="customWidth">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table { width:100%; }
table.customWidth { width:95%; }
```

Answer (score -3):

just write in the css folder `table { width: 100% };`