# How to write a CSS Selector selecting elements NOT having a certain attribute?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

How to write a CSS Selector selecting elements NOT having a certain attribute?

I have 2 `<div>` nodes as follows:

- First:

  ```
  <div class="weEq5" style="will-change; width;">
      <button class="_35EW6">
  ```
- Second:

  ```
  <div class="weEq5">
      <button class="_35EW6">
  ```

I need to select the `<div>` (with the similar class) and each of them which have a similar *descending* `<button>` but without the `style` attribute.

*XPath* seems working fine as:

```
//div[@class and not (@style)]/button
```

I am looking for an equivalent *CssSelector*.

Trials:

```
div[class :not(style)]>button (doesn't works).
```

I have been through the following discussion but they seem to be discarding the *class* attribute as `:not([class])` as in:

- [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class)
- [Is it possible to define in CSS NOT to apply style if element have certain class? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741980/is-it-possible-to-define-in-css-not-to-apply-style-if-element-have-certain-class)

I was looking in similar lines ending with `:not(attribute)`.

Comment: You already have your answer - just substitute "style" where "class" appears in your example.

Comment: @BoltClock Tried but not getting resolved within the [Test](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi) template.

Comment: It's resolving for me using `div:not([style]) button` or `div[class]:not([style]) button`.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks, with exactly the same css `div:not([style])` it still doesn't resolves at my end (shows default 1 Result)

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, it does `div:not(style) button` but somehow can I include the class _attribute_? `div[class]:not(style) button` seems not acceptable.

Comment: `div.weEq5:not([style])`

Comment: @yong `weEq5` is _dynamic_, so we can't take this value

Comment: @BoltClock `div[class]:not(style) button` seems working perfect.

Comment: *Without* the square brackets? Wow, that's... very confusing. Because :not(style) actually means "not a <style> element". If it *doesn't* work *with* the square brackets, then I'm not sure the CSS selector for it is supported at all, and you'll have to stick with XPath.

Comment: Should use the square bracket round `style` like this: `div[class]:not([style])`

Comment: @BoltClock That's where I was stuck. Isn't absence of _style_ attribute implies "not a <style> element" as per the prvailing DOM?

Comment: for css not selector `:not()`, the argument for `:not()` should be valid css selector,  if you use  `not(style)`, the `style` here mean any tag which tag name is `style`, but for `not([style])` , the `[style]` means any tag which has attribute `style`.  One is match by tag name, one is match by tag attribute.  There are different.

Comment: @DebanjanB: No, because attributes and elements are two different things. It's the same reason why you prefix attributes with @ in XPath - in XPath, `style` and `@style` likewise mean different things.

Comment: @DebanjanB - Can you post the answer to this question with little explanation ? It will be helpful for all. Thanks

Comment: @AmitJain See I got the _css-selectors_ working but BoltClock seems not agreeing with the solution pertaining to the functionality and best practices. Can we wait for the _css-selectors_ contributors to have a look at it please?

Comment: What about this one `div.weEq5:not([style]) button` ?

Comment: @NarendraR `weEq5` is dynamic, so we can't take this value into consideration

Comment: @DebanjanB, You are right it would be. the concern about excluding `style` attribute. `div:not([style]) button` this locate the second button. you can take other surrounding element to make this robust.

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533444/css-selector-to-match-an-element-without-attribute-x post

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think more accurate CSS Selector is:

```
div[class]:not([style])>button
```

because the `button` element is a child of `div` element.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 12):

That's the code you're looking for:

```
div:not([style]) button{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Now let's break it down.
We have have four selectors in this example:

1. **div and button** - these select html elements. We can replace it for example with a class selector like `.weEq5`.
2. **:not()** - indicates that we want everything that does not qualify as the selector *inside the brackets*.
3. **[style]** - an [attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) which is very powerful. We can place inside the not any other css selector like html tag names (button or div), class names or ids.

The combination of `div:not([style])` means that we want all divs that do not have a style attribute. After which we have a space and a button means that we want all the buttons that are inside the above selector.

Adding a `>` before the button `div:not([style]) > button` will only select button elements which are direct children of the selected div. It will exclude from selection buttons that are deeper inside the div.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you would write `:not([style])` to match an element that does not have a `style` attribute, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339861/css-not-attribute/14339923#14339923) which emphasizes the use of both `()` and `[]` brackets, in that order.

But if this isn't working in Selenium WebDriver, and worse still if `:not(style)` works exactly like how I would expect `:not([style])` to, then that's a bug with its CSS selector parser, since `:not(style)` actually means "not a `style` element" which makes `div:not(style)` redundant as an element can only either be a `div` or a `style` but not both at the same time. Unless you absolutely require a selector, I strongly recommend using the XPath locator strategy instead of relying on quirks like this with Selenium WebDriver's CSS selector engine that force you to write selectors that are both incorrect and don't work anywhere else that accepts a selector.

Comment: Niche thoughts indeed. Can you help me to understand this phrase you have used _...an element can only either be a `div` or a `style` but not both at the same time..._ because when I was going through [HTML `<div>` Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) the example was based on `<div style="background-color:lightblue">` i.e. a `<div>` tag with _style_ attribute.

Comment: @DebanjanB: The tag name is `div`. What `:not(style)` means is "tag name is not `style`". Since a `div` is a `div`, `:not(style)` will always be true for that element in much the same way that `:not(p)` or `:not(span)` would be true for that element. It has nothing to do with the style attribute.

Comment: Thanks. It got cleared now. `<style>` itself is a _tag_ as well [HTML `<style>` Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) which is not the current usecase we are dealing with.

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand how the situation developed in the first place, where the structure of the page necessitates the CSS rules to be aware of whether "style=..." exists in the document itself. Or even why style=... is being used.

The style attribute is old-school now, pre-CSS I believe. It also takes precedence over anything in the CSS. That attribute does not accept CSS class names. It accepts only native html style properties like "width","height","font" - old-school stuff - ultimately those are what your CSS resolves to, no matter how fancy or obfuscated it is through frameworks: font, width, left, top, float.. and so on.

By use of the class attribute (instead of style) in the document you get infinite control from which to write smart selectors in your CSS.

You can put 3 classes in the class attribute of your div for example, if you want, and have your selectors apply styling to it if 2 of the classes are present but not if all 3 are there. Tonnes of flexibility, no need to override or use "style=..." in the document at all.

Comment: The style attribute is post-CSS. Its syntax is derived *from* CSS, not the other way around. The "native html style properties" you've listed aren't the old-school presentational attributes you're thinking of, but modern (relatively speaking) CSS properties that participate in the same cascade as the rest of Cascading Style Sheets. In fact, these days the presentational attributes are implemented using CSS, though I'm not sure if it was ever implemented the other way around when the first browsers to support CSS emerged in 1996/97.

Comment: All said, the use case here is not styling elements with CSS, as can be gleaned from the tags, this is an automated testing use case using Selenium WebDriver, which doesn't involve applying or overriding CSS.