# Protractor Conditional Selector

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, protractor, e2e-testing

I am using Selenium Protractor and want to select all elements from the following list except one that contains text "Cat" and then perform some operations on the remaining ones.

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="childDiv">Dog</div>
    <div class="childDiv">Goat</div>
    <div class="childDiv">Bird</div>
    <div class="childDiv">Cat</div>
    <div class="childDiv">Zebra</div>
</div>
```

Is there a selector by cssContainingText (or some other) in which I can give a condition to select all elements except the one containing text "Cat"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a *List* selecting all the elements except one that contains text **Cat** using the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath*:

  ```
  //div[@class='mainDiv']//div[@class='childDiv'][not(contains(.,'Cat'))]
  ```

When using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors):

> The :contains pseudo-class isn't in the CSS Spec and is not supported by either Firefox or Chrome (even outside WebDriver). You can find a detailed discussion in [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException with “span:contains('string')”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883572/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidselectorexception-with-spancontainsstring/47884814#47884814)

However, if the elements always appears within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) in a specific order, e.g. **Cat** always at the forth child, you can also use:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  div.mainDiv div.childDiv:not(:nth-child(4))
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [While fetching all links,Ignore logout link from the loop and continue navigation in selenium java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57293901/while-fetching-all-links-ignore-logout-link-from-the-loop-and-continue-navigatio/57294355#57294355)
- [How to write a CSS Selector selecting elements NOT having a certain attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927485/how-to-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-attribute)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The upper one worked for me using xpath.